# Rails 4 - how to rewrite ".find_by_sql" to the query using ActiveRecords methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, model

I stuck on converting a query that I use (and is basically a raw SQL) to a query using ActiveRecord's methods. The reason I am trying to convert it is that I need to use scopes one it.

```
find_by_sql("SELECT 
               COUNT(s.id) AS count_all,
               SUM(s.gross_profit) AS sum_gross_profit,   
               se.user_id,
               u.id,
               u.first_name,
               u.last_name,
               u.role
             FROM shipments s 
             INNER JOIN senders se ON se.id = s.sender_id 
             INNER JOIN users a ON a.id = se.user_id 
             WHERE ((#{status}) 
               AND (se.admin_id IS NOT NULL)
             GROUP BY se.user_id 
             ORDER BY count_all DESC")
  }
```

How to convert all those `s`, `se`, `u` aliases and 2 `INNER JOIN`s into an ActiveRecord query?

**EDIT: What I've tried:**

```
select("COUNT(shipments.id) AS count_all,
        SUM(shipments.gross_profit) AS sum_gross_profit,   
        senders.admin_id,
        users.id,
        users.first_name,
        users.last_name,
        users.role")
.joins("INNER JOIN senders ON senders.id = shipments.sender_id 
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id = senders.user_id")
.where("((#{status}) 
          AND (senders.admin_id IS NOT NULL)")
.group("senders.user_id") 
.order("count_all DESC")
```

But this returns only output like this:

```
{16=>41, 46=>34, 54=>2, 55=>1, 56=>1}:Hash
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the AR doc? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Look at joins, includes, where, count, group.

Comment: Added the current query I am trying....

Comment: if you have queries like these, it's usually best to keep them in sql

Comment: never do this `.where("((#{status}) 
          AND (senders.admin_id IS NOT NULL)")` unless sql-injection is your friend

Comment: Thank you @phoet for your comment. I intentionally tried to keep it as it is, in an SQL format, but the need of using another scopes for this query forces me to rewrite it to the ActiveRecord's methods.

Comment: I would pull sum and count out of the the sql and use the corollary active record methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want at the end are `User` instances, with a couple extra attributes. In that case ActiveRecord is going to use `FROM users`, so you need to rewrite your joins a bit. Since everything is an `INNER JOIN` that's easy. So I'd do this:

```
User.select("COUNT(shipments.id) AS count_all,
        SUM(shipments.gross_profit) AS sum_gross_profit,   
        senders.admin_id,
        users.*")
.joins("INNER JOIN senders ON senders.user_id = users.id 
        INNER JOIN shipments ON shipments.sender_id = senders.id")
.where("(SOMETHING HERE)
          AND senders.admin_id IS NOT NULL")
.group("users.id") 
.order("count_all DESC")
```

I took out the `#{status}` because that looks like a serious security flaw. You should learn how to use `where("foo = ?", bar)` to prevent SQL injection.

Also there were some mismatched parens even in the original SQL, so I cleaned those up.